# Regex for CSV split including multiple double quotes

Tags: python, regex, csv, sublimetext3, double-quotes

I have a CSV column data containing text. Each row is separated with double quotes `"`

Sample text in a row is similar to this (**notice**: new lines and the spaces before each line *are intended*)

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
 consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
 aliqua. Ut ""enim ad"" minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
 ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat ""nulla pariatu"""
"ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure ""dolor in"" reprehenderit 
 in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
 Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt 
 mollit anim id est laborum."
```

The above represent 2 subsequent rows.

I want to select as separated groups all the text contained between every first double quote `"` (starting a line) and every LAST double quote `"`

As you can see tho, there are line break in the text, along with subsequent escaped double quotes `""` wich are part of the text that I need to select.

I came up with something like this

```
(?s)(?!")[^\s](.+?)(?=")
```

but the multiple double quotes are breaking my desired match

I'm a real novice with regex, so I think maybe I'm missing something very basic. Dunno if relevant but I'm using Sublime Text 3 so should be python I think.

What can I do to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO1wB6/2)

This regex will match either a non-quote, or 2 consequent double quotes inside double quotation marks.

How does it work? Let me share a graphics from [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VMpVzFMT_JuSSV19):

[image]

With the regex, we match:

- `"` - (1) - a literal quote
- `[^"]*` - (2, 3) - 0 or more characters other than a quote (yes, including a newline, this is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)), if there are none, then the regex searches for the final literal quote (6)
- `(?:""[^"]*)*` - (4,5) - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `""` - (4) - double double quotation marks
  - `[^"]*` - (5) - 0 or more characters other than a quote
- `"` - (6) - the final literal quote.

This works faster than [`"(?:[^"]|"")*"`](https://regex101.com/r/nO1wB6/4) (although yielding the same results), because the processing the former is linear, involving much less backtracking.

Comment: Actually, the regex will work in both Python and PCRE engines. Sublime Text uses PCRE engine for search and replace, and Oniguruma for syntax highlighting.

Comment: That's the deal thank you! Tho can you explain me WHY it works? the non matching tag thing is kinda tripping me out, why does it includes break lines too?

Comment: Meh RTFM issue: "Unlike the dot, [negated character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) also match (invisible) line break characters." Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [python](/questions/tagged/python) , then you do not need [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) , you can directly use the standard [csv library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), and double doublequotes inside a single row would be handled automatically. Example (For the csv you posted above in `a.csv`) -

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('a.csv','r') as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     for row in reader:
...             print(row)
...
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \n consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod\n tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna \n aliqua. Ut "enim ad" minim veniam,\n quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi \n ut aliquip ex ea commodo\n consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse\n cillum dolore eu fugiat "nulla pariatu"']
['ex ea commodo\n consequat. Duis aute irure "dolor in" reprehenderit \n in voluptate velit esse\n cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \n Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non\n proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt \n mollit anim id est laborum.']
```

---

This was handled correctly by the `csv` module basically because `"` is the default [quotechar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) , so anything within two `"` is considered part of that single column, even if its `\n` or spaces, etc.

Also, `csv` module has another argument called [`doublequote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.doublequote) that is -

> Controls how instances of quotechar appearing inside a field should be themselves be quoted. **When True, the character is doubled**. When False, the escapechar is used as a prefix to the quotechar. It defaults to True.

Comment: This is only good if OP is building some Python-based plug-in for Sublime Text.

Comment: The question has Python tag, so I gave a python based answer.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but @stribizhev is right, and you are too. I placed Python tag only because I know sublime text is built with it and because I know (very basically) that regex can change some functions based on what language is using. +1 indeed tho as I think this will be useful anyway for someone else!